# Dissection puzzle from the Gardner's book. How to define points without tools?

Tags: dissection, paper-folding

The figure shows a fairly well-known puzzle from the book by Martin Gardner. You need to cut the regular hexagonal star into pieces and fold the square.

[image]

**Question:** how to define points (marked in red) without using additional tools?

I am looking for an origami technique.

Comment: What makes you think that Martin Gardner defined those points without any additional tools?

Comment: I haven't done the calculation, but I believe my comments on [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/102553/can-you-fold-a-square-into-a-square-of-one-third-the-area) also applies here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure *all* of Martin Gardner's dissection puzzle solutions are constructible with compass and straightedge (and therefore paper folding too).

Comment: Just checked and the puzzles include regular 7 and 9-gons, where compass and straightedge may fail, but paper folding will still be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is the most elegant way of doing it but it does the job:

> [image]
>  
>  Make a crease at the midline (in particular, marking the midpoint M of the base) and cut off the top and bottom triangle.
>  
>  Align one of the triangles with its base on the midline and its midline on the base as in the picture. Its tip marks the point N. Make a vertical crease through the midpoint B of N and corner A.
>  
>  Insert the two triangles on the left as indicated in the picture and mark the long vertical line trough their tips. Fold through B such that M falls on that vertical line at new point M'.
>  Mark the horizontal midline and fold through A such that M' falls onto the horizontal midline. (Note: The fold is meets the top of the shape very close to but not exactly at the vertical midline.) This fold is one of the two we require.
>  Fold through corner C and perpendicular to this fold to obtain the other one.

> Let's assume the small triangles have sides of length 1.
>  Then the square will have area $3\sqrt{3}$ and its side will be $\sqrt{3\sqrt{3}}$.
>  We can check that the distance $AM'$ is half that length. Indeed, by construction we have $AM'^2=BM^2-AB^2$. These have lengths $AB=\frac {3-\sqrt{3}}{4}$ and $BM=\frac{3+\sqrt{3}}{4}$ such that $AM^2=\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4}$ as claimed.

Answer (score 1):

No solution – an experiment

> This began before the "origami" restriction was edited into the question.
>
>  I asked myself: does it *matter* where point 2 is, so long as it forms a right angle?
>  First I cut off half the paper and used one edge as a ruler to draw line AB.
>  I then positioned the right-angled corner of the paper so that its sides touch C and D.
>  And drew the lines CE and DE to its corner, then extended DE to F.
>
>  The lines weres delicate and thin and did not copy/resize well, so I re-drew with a ruler.
>  I then cut it along the green lines (not AB) and reformed the parts as shown.
>
>  [image]
>
>  The result isn't a square but a rectangle, so I have not solved the puzzle.
>
>  Are the two top corners square?
>  Looking at the top right corner, the two sliver angles come from points C and D.
>  The other parts of C and D always sum to 90°, so the slivers always sum to 30°.